# Django's {% include with var="val" %} updates context

Tags: django, django-templates

I just figured out, that if you include subtemplate using `with`, variables will be available in base template. Very easy to reproduce:

```
Test: {{ test }}
{% include "tpl.txt" with test="passed" %}
Test: {{ test }}
```

Output:

```
Test:
Test: passed
```

Is it a bug?

**UPD.** I must say that inside `tpl.txt` there is inclusion tag with `take_context=True`. Also this inclusion tag do this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('my_tag.txt', takes_context=True)
def my_tag(context):
    context.update({'new': 'key'})
    return context
```

If you don't `update` context, or if you do `context['new'] = 'key'` it works as expected. If you do `update` - all the variables you pass to `{% include %}` using `with` become available later in template. Still it's kind of wierd, because variables become available in parent template, and not updated keys ("new") become available, but `{% include %}` variables. The problem is localized though.

Comment: Which version of django you use?  Can't reproduce in 1.7.

Comment: I think that is expected, the template included is evaluated in current context which might be enhanced with new variables. Not sure about the latest django versions though.

Comment: @catavaran, yes, I wasn't clear enough. Still this behavior is wierd. Updated.